# setState in an interval consuming huge memory

Tags: react-native

I tried create a countdown timer and found that `setState` in an interval consuming a lot of memory and it will grow until it crash.

I tried creating a fresh new react-native app using `react-native init intervaltest`

then I got this in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    countdownNumber: 10000000
  };      

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (!this.interval) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          countdownNumber: prevState.countdownNumber - 1
        }));
      }, 10);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { countdownNumber } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>{countdownNumber}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } 
}   

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
});
```

It is a very simple code anyway. Is there any way to solve this memory thirsty behavior of react-native?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `setInterval` is called in `componentDidMount` and `componetDidMount` will be called once in whole `component life-cycle`. So, the function within setInterval will be called once only. i.e. just after the first render but upon successive render, the `componentDidMount` won't be called.

Simple solution is:

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    countdownNumber: 10000000
  };      

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (!this.interval) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          countdownNumber: prevState.countdownNumber - 1
        }));
      }, 10);
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.countdownNumber === 1){ 
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    const { countdownNumber } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>{countdownNumber}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } 
}
```

[Memory leak due to setInterval](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-stop-memory-leaks-with-componentwillunmount-lifecycle-method-in-react)::If we `unmount` the component before calling `clearInterval`, there is a memory leak because the `interval` that is set in `componentDidMount` starts timer and the timer is not stopped when component unmount's. React provides the `componentWillUnmount` life-cycle method as an opportunity to clear anything that needs to be cleared when the component is `unmounted` / `removed`.

Comment: In addition, the interval in the root component and will never be unmount. The problem is when you setState for many times the memory consuming is growing each time.